# Read a Value of a Child Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can anyone please help? I'm stuck, can't retrieve simple data. This is my code:

[image]

And this is my database:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as an image, add it as a text.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `seller` note, is a direct child of your database root, to get the value of your `userType` property, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userTypeRef = rootRef.child("seller").child(uid).child("BasicInfo").child("userType");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String userType = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", userType);

        if(userType.equals("buyer")) {
            //Your logic
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
userTypeRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Please note that logic regarding the value you get from the database is placed inside the callback because Firebase API's are asynchronous. For more information, please also see my answer from the following post:

- [How to return DataSnapshot value as a result of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)